# PHP & SMTP2GO - Sending bulk emails on local site vs remote site

Tags: php, email, server, smtp

We have a website which sends out bulk emails to customers. We are trying to identify how many emails we can send per hour using SMTP2GO. We are using a CRON job to handle the sending of the emails and currently have it set to send 10 emails every 5 minutes (120 per hour). However, because there is 3000+ customers it takes over 5 hours to send them all out. Ideally we would like this to take an hour. We looked into SMTP2GO and found that they have a send limit of 200,000 emails per hour which is more than enough.

What we have done so far is to create a copy of the live site on a local environment and up the send limit to 250 per 5 minutes (3,000 an hour) which seems to work fine without any issues. However, I'm nervous about pushing this up to the live site as I'm not sure how the servers differ from one another.

Is it safe to say that the local environment will be the same as the live server? The live site is running on a dedicated server. If not, how do i know for sure what the limit would be on the live site? Would i have to setup another dedicated server and use this to test instead?

Comment: I think you said you were using `SMTP2GO` server to send email. So where you send the request to send the emails from  is kinda irrelevant, Isn't it?

Comment: Yes correct, however the CRON which handles the sending of the emails needs to connect to the database and get the relevant data to send in the emails. So maybe it's more a question of execution time.